how to enable, disable, experiment with, and monitor the use of Receive Side Scaling (RSS) technology on my system LINUX
I am specifically looking for instructions on how to enable, disable and monitor the use of Recieve Side Scaling (RSS) technology on my Ubuntu system.
I have tried different ways to activate and deactivate RSS, without success on my Ubuntu Server 22.04, using commands such as:
ethtool -K ens16 rxhash off -- ethtool -L ens16 combined 1 rx 0 tx 0

I'm using this NIC: Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection;
With these specifications:
driver: igb
version: 5.15.0-107-generic 
firmware-version: 3.25, 0x8000060b, 1.654.0

Output of ethtool -l ens16:
Channel parameters for ens16: 

Pre-set maximums: 
RX:     n/a 
TX:     n/a 
Other:      1 
Combined:   4 

Current hardware settings: 
RX:     n/a 
TX:     n/a 
Other:      1 
Combined:   4


Have you consulted docs visible from an on-line search, such as https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/performance_tuning_guide/network-rss ?  That one doesn't seem to make any reference to ethtool.

https://github.com/stroboscope/igb -- check the README, there's some relevant parameters you can specify if loading the driver as a kernel module
